# How to calculate a volume integral from a data file containing $x$, $y$ and $z$ coordinates and electric field value at each $(x,y,z)$?

Tags: integration

I have a data file from a simulation that contains $E$-field values at different coordinates $(x,y,z)$. I want to calculate the integral $\int E^{2} dV$ over a cylindrical volume in Python or MATLAB. Can someone please help me in calculating this integral?

It is fine if you don't give Python or MATLAB code, but please just explain me how to do this integral using the $E$-field data.

Comment: How about doing it like you would normally do? Define $dx$, $dy$ and $dz$ as infinitesimal elements at a particular value of $z$, then integrate along $x$ and $y$ by discrete summation. Then integrate that result along the $z$ axis? You will have to use $3$ loops.

Comment: A lot depends on the language you use as well, in Python this is easy. In MATLAB, it will take work imo.